# zlogin usage in Runeck task

Tags: rundeck

As part of rundeck task i'm trying to login to a global zone, use the command zoneadm list and trying to login to each of the local zone [to shut down various apps & to issue reboot] using the command `/usr/sbin/zlogin` and execute hostname command to ensure it did login to localzone
however this is not working

Is there a better way to do this? Please guide

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example? Any log job output to check any clue?

Comment: `ARG=`echo $1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
declare -a zone_arr
if [[ $ARG == "server1" ]]; then
    zonelist=$(/usr/sbin/zoneadm list | grep -v global)
    zone_arr=($zonelist)
    for lzone in "${zone_arr[@]}"
    do
        echo -e "Logging into local zone \n"
        /usr/sbin/zlogin lzone
        echo `hostname`
        ~.
 done
fi`
This is the code i'm trying to execute as part of task in rundeck
This the error i'm getting...
`line 13: ~.: command not found`

Comment: Also i'm not sure how else to use Rundeck to login to local zones to automate reboot, any references would be of great help

Comment: Your job are dispatching to the right node that has this command (zlogin)? If you need to execute anything to a remote node the job must be configured to be dispatched to that node, for that edit your job, go to "Nodes" tab and select "Dispatch to nodes" on "Nodes" section, then you can select your node at "Node Filter" textbox (you can use wildcards to select multiple nodes) of course you need to define your node in your Node Source first, take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOA-kWse22g (you can see Rundeck 2.11 in the video but is the same process for latest version).

Comment: yes its dispatching the correct nodes.
yes Node Source first is selected
`zoneadm list` command works
but `zlogin` to local zone command doesnt work...

Comment: Maybe the best way is to execute zlogin as "no interactive mode" in your script, check this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-1592/z.login.ov-10/index.html (Non-Interactive Mode). Checking about zlogin seems to open a new interactive terminal that rundeck can't handle as "normal terminal". It similar to this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4506#issuecomment-466118234

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your job is dispatching to your remote node correctly, you can call the command on "Commands" (right panel) pointing to your node (referenced in the "Nodes" textbox) in that way you can discard possible path/user rights issue, take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOA-kWse22g). Now, `zlogin` seems an interactive shell, and as you can [see](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4506#issuecomment-466118234), you need to use it in the [non-interactive mode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-1592/z.login.ov-10/index.html).

Comment: Since rundeck wasnt that helpful in setting up automating server reboot, i'm making use of ansible currently to set it up. Thanks a lot for your prompt responses!!! Cheers!